# How do I create a foreign key in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacSSN text(9) primary key,
FacFirstName Text(30) null,
FacLastName Text(50) null,
FacCity text(50) null,
FacState text(2) null,
FacDept text (6) null,
FacRank text(6) null,
FacSalary currency null,
FacSupervisor text(9) null,
FacHireDate datetime null,
facZipCode text(9) null,
offerNo text(6) ,

FOREIGN KEY offerNo REFERENCES ClassOffering (OfferNo)

);
```

I have another table called ClassOffering created with "OfferNo" already in it.  I need to create a foreign key in the table above that 'links' to ClassOffering.  I am using Access.

Comment: Brandon, please post the ClassOffering table from your previous question.  Your issue is addressed in my answer about data types needing to match.

Comment: The previous table was class enrollment.

Comment: Now I feel foolish, I tried to make sure they were the same before I posted this assumption... In either case, the table will allow myself, or someone else to assist you.

Comment: All good, after looking back, I actually posted the 'class enrollment' table but I accidentally labeled it 'offering'.  I edited and corrected it, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brandon, you will not be able to create a foreign key with `offerNo` when defined as `text(6)`

The data types for `forign keys` need to match and the ClassOffering table from your previous question has `offerNo INTEGER`.  Change the `text(6)` to `INTEGER` to match, and the foreign key will work

You need to put parenthesis around the column offerNo, like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (offerNo) REFERENCES ClassOffering (OfferNo)
```

Comment: I have changed OfferNo to an int to match the rest of my tables, however when running the query, I get an error of "Syntax error in constraint clause."  Personally, I can't see any errors with the clause.

Comment: I've updated my answer to have the required parenthesis for the syntax to be correct.

Comment: Yes, I realized this about 30 seconds ago and just refreshed to post this myself.  Exactly correct and allowed the query to run.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note you can declare the `FOREIGN KEY` inline i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacSSN text(9) primary key,
FacFirstName Text(30) null,
FacLastName Text(50) null,
FacCity text(50) null,
FacState text(2) null,
FacDept text (6) null,
FacRank text(6) null,
FacSalary currency null,
FacSupervisor text(9) null,
FacHireDate datetime null,
facZipCode text(9) null,
offerNo integer null REFERENCES ClassOffering (OfferNo)
);
```

Comment: Took a decade to get an upvote for this, but thanks.