# I need to write a validation rule for a field so that all entries into that field match with at least on entry in another table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

Let me try to explain best I can...

I have a table where I enter customer data. Each of those customers have a specialty code. Those codes, when entered, MUST be one of the codes we have in an already existing table called SPECIALTY_CODES.

If the entry does not exist in that other table, I want it to raise an error.

So how can I write a validation rule that checks to see if the entry matches with at least one value in the SPECIALTY_CODES table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MS-Access why not just set the field to use the type Lookup & Relationship?
The ability to restrict values and raise an error are built into Access already, in Access 2007-2010 you can click the arrow next to the field name and it will allow you to set that filed as a Lookup ... a wizard comes up and on the last page you'll see 'Enable Data Integrity' click that and for your case 'Restrict Delete' then you'll get an error when you try to enter something wrong.

Here's an office link for more details:
[Create a Lookup Field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-lookup-field-87e84cbd-d60c-4473-8a98-3e391c42f239)

Answer (score 0):

The validation rule you're looking for is referred to as a **foreign key constraint** in relational databases. I think you can do this via the Access GUI table designer, but via a SQL query it looks like this:

```
alter table CUSTOMERDATA alter column SPECIALTY_CODE <datatype>
    add constraint FK_SPECIALTYCODES references SPECIALTY_CODES (SPECIALTYCODE)
```

Substitute the appropriate column, field and data type names. The data types must match between the tables. This will stop any records from being entered in `CUSTOMERDATA` which do not have a `SPECIALTYCODE` that appears on the `SPECIALTYCODES table.

See also [How do I create a foreign key in access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059861/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-in-access) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243835(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I tried your code in SQL view but didn't have any success. I had some issues with the <datatype> and references keywords of the statement. Access didn't seem to recognize them.

Comment: You have to specify the actual datatype of the field you're using. Try the fixed syntax in my edit.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to alter the column, just the table: `alter table CUSTOMERDATA add constraint FK_SPECIALTYCODES references SPECIALTY_CODES (SPECIALTYCODE);`